# How to receive notification regarding the BT connection states

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-bluetooth

i am trying to receive notifications when the connection state changed "connecting,connected,disonnectig,disconnected". i registered for ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED, but i always receive the Log in the "default" statement of the "switch-case".

please let me know how to receive to be notified correctly regarding the states mentioned in the switch-case in the below code?

**code**:

```
final int connState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (connState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("BT STATE_CONNECTED.");

                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("BT STATE_CONNECTED.");

                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("BT is STATE_CONNECTING.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("BT STATE_DISCONNECTING.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("BT STATE_DISCONNECTED.");
                break;
            default:
                Log.wtf(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "connState: UNHANDELED CASE."));
                break;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE
```

instead of

```
BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE
```